# Build Android App bundle from the command line

Tags: android, adb, google-play-console, bundletool

My APK file is already signed (with jarsigner) and compressed (with zipalign). I do it via a bash script. Though I'm getting a warning in Play Console to use Android App Bundle:

> Reduce the size of your next release using the Android App Bundle. Your app could be 15.4% smaller if you used the Android App Bundle.

I know I have to use [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool?hl=en) to use it in command line. The documentation is though too long and cumbersome.

Imagine I have such a file `myApp.apk` (already signed and compressed). Which command should I run to have the Android App Bundle file to upload to Google Play Console?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very simple.
You can create android app bundles (.aab) file from android source by this command :

```
gradlew bundle
```

OR

```
gradle bundle
```

Comment: To add bundleRelease will build hte release version

Comment: so where's the output?

Comment: The output is an android app bundles (.aab) that you can use it to publish your app to google play.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply convert an APK to an App Bundle. You have to use a build system that supports building App Bundles from source, like Android Studio (which uses Android Gradle plugin) or others.

Bundletool has a `build-bundle` command but it is meant to use by build systems since you need already precompiled dex code, and resources compiled in a proto format.

Comment: it's possible, solution here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729#issuecomment-507569844

Answer (score -1):

go to android folder and using bundleRelease command you can generate the .aab file

> step 1: cd android
>
> step 2: ./gradlew bundleRelease

you will find the (.aab) file inside output release folder